# Matched Rows From Two Table and Display Them As New Row

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose, I've data in a table say **Table 1** as follows:

```
QuesID QuesName       
     1 Question 1
     2 Question 2
     3 Question 3
     4 Question 4
```

In **Table 2**, as follows:

```
ID QuesID MainQuesID
 1      4          1
 2      2          2
```

I want to have the following output:

```
QuesID QuesName       
     1 Question 1
     1 Question 4
     2 Question 2
     2 Question 2
     3 Question 3
     4 Question 4
```

Is it actually possible to do with Sql? I tried the following but it will return all the questions even if it does not match the ID (Order by MainQuesID):

```
SELECT m.QuesID
     , m.QuesName
  FROM Table_1 m 
 GROUP 
    BY m.QuesID
     ,m.QuesName
 UNION ALL 
SELECT k.QuesID
     , m.QuesName
  FROM Table_2 k
```

Comment: Why do you have a column called QuesName in Table 2? And what purpose does `ID` serve in that table?

Comment: ID is the primary key in the Table 2. Never mind. It was repeated.

Comment: So, each question can have more than one mainquesid?

Comment: OK, so next. Where does title and qstnID come from?

Comment: yeah same question for me..title :)

Comment: Table 2 will have extra questions and should be showed up according to the 'MainQuesID' order. Updated the post.

Comment: I have posted one code..Can you pls check whether its working fine or not

Comment: @Raavi I've checked the query. It did not work but thanks a lot for your afford.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, from the result you posted, that entries from the `Table_2` are to be listed by their `MainQuesID`.

```
SELECT * from 
    ((SELECT t1.QuesID, t1.QuesName FROM Table_1 t1)
    UNION (SELECT t2.MainQuesID as QuesID, t1.Title as QuesName
        FROM Table_2 t2 JOIN Table_1 t1 ON t1.QuesID = t2.QuesID))
    as union_table
    ORDER BY union_table.QuesID
```

The Table_2 is joined with Table_1 to get the Question Title  for each qstnID.

Then both tables are brought into the Format (`QuesID`, `QuesName`), then unioned them, then ordered them by QuesID.

Comment: It worked. I've a question. You did not use any joins, so how does the query work?

Comment: My first try assumed, Table_2 contained  the QuesName already, then no Join is needed. With the Question as it is now, a Join is needed (see my edit).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Got it now.

Answer (score 0):

this is the result you need:

```
select QuesID,Quesname from
(select QuesID,Quesname from table_1

union all

select id,QuesName from Table_2) as a order by QuesID
```

[image]

Same as the result you wanted

Answer (score -1):

Try Below code once

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 (
    QuesID INT
    ,QuesName VARCHAR(100)
    )
INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES (
    1
    ,'Question 1'
    )
INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES (
    2
    ,'Question 2'
    )
INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES (
    3
    ,'Question 3'
    )
INSERT INTO #table1
VALUES (
    4
    ,'Question 4'
    )

CREATE TABLE #table2 (
    ID INT
    ,QuesID INT
    ,QuesName VARCHAR(100)
    ,MainQuesID INT
    )
INSERT INTO #table2
VALUES (
    1
    ,4
    ,'Question 4'
    ,1
    )
INSERT INTO #table2
VALUES (
    2
    ,2
    ,'Question 2'
    ,2
    )

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT QuesID
        ,QuesName
    FROM #table1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT MainQuesID
        ,QuesName
    FROM #table2
    ) A
ORDER BY QuesID
```